# Vue-router and deeply nested routes

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

Given following Layout component:

Layout:

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="sidebar-container">
      <router-view name='sidebar'></router-view>
    </div>
    <div class="main">
      <router-view></router-view>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Is there a way to specify in deeply nested route to use `sidebar` outlet?

```
const routes = {
  path: '',
  components: { default: SomeMainComponent },
  children: [{
    path: 'foo',
    children: [{
      path: 'bar',
      components: { sidebar: BarSide }
    }]
  }]
}
```

It seems that router is only looking to resolve the router outlets of the direct route parent - if I move `components: { side: BarSide }` to the `foo` definition, then the component is rendered as expected. As is, component is not even being created.

Is there a way to achieve this?

JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xptkhf4z/5/ - clicking on a `With helper` link updates the route, keeps default component rendered but does not render the additional component in helper slot.

Comment: why is your router-view name `sidebar` but in route definition its `side` only?

Comment: @kcsujeet - Typo -it is only a pseudo-code to highlight the issue I'm having. I've added jsfiddle link as well.

Comment: you don't have component definition for the route `foo`. you need a `router-view` in the template for the child routes of `foo` and if you want a secondary router view there then its where you use `named router view`. check the official documentation for nested routes: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/nested-routes.html

Comment: @kcsujeet - I've read the documentation mutliple times and did not find any help there regarding deeply nested routes. Jsfiddle example defines a component in all the paths, but the problem still persists.

Comment: are you trying to render `UserProfilePreview` component inside of `UserEmailsSubscriptions` component ??? is that the final goal ??

Comment: @kcsujeet - No, I want to have a single layout component, with reusable router-views that can be optionally used in deeply nested routes. The top level components consists of google map component and I need to route to qutie a few places that will need to use the sidebar (and few other that do not need sidebar). Again, all the code above are abstract example of the problem I need to solve and do not represent actual code - the jsfiddle is modified version of example given in the vue-router documentation.

Comment: your `helper` router-view is in `UserSettings` component while it should be in `UserEmailsSubscriptions` . its because in your router definition you're using named router-view for the path `helper` which is a child route of the path `emails`

Comment: @kcsujeet - This is exactly the problem - I need to use that router-view in the descendant that is not a direct child and I am asking if there is any way around this (like defining router-view global  or something).

In the example, I cannot move the `helper` definition to the parent route, as it should not be there, the additional content should be only displayed in the nested child. So far it seems it is not possible to achieve that using vue-router so I'm writing my own plugin.

Comment: check this out. https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/2324 . navigate to `rwaltenberg` 's answer. this should work. using the meta properties of vue routes you should be able to render a vue component where you want it.

Comment: And that is what I am looking for. Thanks. :)

Comment: please, let us know if that worked. :)

Comment: It seems to work - I still think I'll go with a plugin as I might need some extra power-ups to the solution above (like multiple sidebars at the same time). But yes, using meta instead of components roughly works (I might to need to use `$route.matched` instead of `$route.meta` for deeper nested routes)

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't have the full answer, you seem to have to include a component on each nested level. That can either be your page component or a layout component.

This should work:

```
const routes = {
  path: '',
  components: { default: SomeMainComponent },
  children: [{
    path: 'foo',
    component: () => import('layouts/DummyLayoutComponent'),
    children: [{
      path: 'bar',
      components: { sidebar: BarSide }
    }]
  }]
}
```

The `DummyLayoutComponent` should be a neutral layout, because it is added to the layout of `SomeMainComponent`.

I find it a little awkward that we seem to have to define an "empty" layout just to get this to work. But maybe I'm just missing an important point.

Comment: This is basically what I've ended up doing anyway for nested routes - otherwise the child routes do not render at all as there is no parent router-view (however I've named it AbstractRouteView). You are right, this can be used to define all the required slots, probably by looping over `$scopedSlots` object. This is still sub-optimal though, as it requires all the components between the slot-owner and the child to include that slot. I have finally resolved it with a custom "Container" plugin, a bit like `content_for` in rails.